# change vertical lines position in column chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a table which im trying to convert to a highchart column chart and im having a small issue with the setting the vertical lines.

i want place it in between each set of column blocks. Please check the image

[image]

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Daily Sales</th>
            <th>Average</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>2000</th>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2005</th>
            <td>245</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2010</th>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in my highcharts code

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
                data: {
                   table: 'datatable'
                },
                exporting: { enabled: false },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',


                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },

                labels: {
                   format: '{value}'
               },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,

                    title: {
                        text: 'Chart'
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    gridLineColor: '#000',
                    lineColor: '#000',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    crosshair: true,



                },
                colors: [
                         '#990000',
                         '#993399',

                     ],
                legend: {

                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',

                },
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 1,
                    y2: 0
               },

                  },
            });
        });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Set the [tickmarkPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) parameter as 'between'. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9rzfm2s/

Comment: @SebastianBochan I just tried it but when i use it with number like years in the xAxis it doesnt work . Please check http://jsfiddle.net/5m3kgkvs/3/

Comment: At the beginning you should set between value instead of before. The tickmarkPlacement works only with categories. Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/555jex1q/

Comment: @SebastianBochan awesome... Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set 'between' value for the tickmarkPlacement parameter, whiich works only with categories.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  tickmarkPlacement: 'between'
}
```

Fixed demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/555jex1q